# Excel: Select Range in Formula based on column value

Tags: excel, vba

I have two tables that have similar columns:

Table1:

**Date**   **Ticker**    **Data**

May  2008, XYZ, 6

Aug 2010, XYZ, 5

Sep 2008, ABC, 7

Table2:

**Date** **Ticker** **Data**

EDIT:
[image: Sample Data]
* Apply SMALL formula below to ABC tickers, XYZ etc...

I'm trying to apply this formula: `=SMALL($A:$A,COUNTIF($A:$A,"<="&A1))`

which finds the nearest date in Table 2 from the date in Table 1

Table 2 is huge and has numerous entries of all kinds of dates and tickers.

The problem is I need to apply the SMALL formula above only to similar tickers. How do I adjust the range in the formula to ONLY apply to range with the same ticker in Table 1 and Table2? There are a few thousand so can't manually name the ranges.

Thanks!

Comment: Expand the COUNTIF into a COUNTIFS `=SMALL($A:$A,COUNTIFS($A:$A,"<="&A1,$B:$B,D1))` (Where `D1` is the cell reference of the ticker like ABC or XYZ of the row you're looking at in Table 1)

Comment: Thanks @tigeravatar that fixed the TICKER reference but now I'm just getting the minimum value with similar ticker (12/10/2002). I am looking for the Previous available date than the one in Table 1. So for example, if in Table 1 Ticker = ABC and Date = 12/10/2006 it should return 1/10/2006 from Table 2.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work for me for Excel 2010 & 2013:

```
{=max(if(ticker range = TICKER,if(date range <= DATE,date range)))}
```

CTRL+SHFT+ENTER as it is an array

I believe Excel 2016 has MaxIFS function that might make it bit easier. Will have to apply to spreadsheet and see how it works.